# How return .Json and .XML format based on URL request

Tags: c#, json, xml, api, asp.net-web-api2

I write ASP.Net web API using visual studio. My question is how can I return `.Json` and `.XML` both format based on URL request. like this, If I type this (`http://localhost:15827/api/Person.Json`) on browser Output should be `JSON` , If I type this (`http://localhost:15827/api/Person.XML`) on browser Output should be `XML`

This is my part of my code.which returns normally person data from a database

```
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web.Http;

namespace SoftAPI.Controllers
{
    public class PersonController : ApiController
    {

        [HttpGet]
        // GET: api/Person
        public ArrayList Get()
        {
            PersonPersistence obj = new PersonPersistence();
            return obj.getPerson();
        }

    }
}
```

I tried this one, but it does't work for me

```
public class ProjectController : ApiController
{

    [HttpGet("api/Person.{format}"), FormatFilter]
    // GET: api/Person
    public ArrayList Get()
    {
        PersonPersistence obj = new PersonPersistence();
        return obj.getPerson();
    }

}
```

How can I do this. Thank you

Comment: Any reason why the [automatic content negotiation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/content-negotiation) isn't acceptable? Add an `Accept` header such as `text/xml` or `application/json` and you're good to go. Lots of useful info in the linked article to help you take your path.

Comment: @spender hello sir, I new to this subject, If you can please give me an code example as answer, thanks is advance

Comment: @spender hello sir, I new to this subject, If you can please give me an code example as answer, thanks is advance

Comment: Where will you be consuming this data from?

Comment: @spender This is my university project. I **basically I need to display this data in web browser or test client application such as postman (according to coursework client app does not compulsory)**. and I also plan to display this data in c# desktop application. That Consume application code like this tutorial http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/create-a-web-api-and-call-it-using-a-desktop-client-application/

Comment: Then simply pass the Accept head with postman.

Comment: @john not clear sir. my tested code gave me error . could you please give me a sample code here

Comment: Perhaps you'd include a screenshot of your postman request headers?